# Can an in-file stylecop suppression be re-enabled?

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have a source file with a small problem area requiring a StyleCop suppression rule. I've put the suppression in the source file above the problem area. I'd like to re-enable the rule for the rest of the file. Is there a way to do this?
Example:

```
[module: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules", "SAXXXX: SomeStyleCopRule", Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            // ...some code which erroneously triggers StyleCop warning unless suppressed above...
        }
    }
    // Re-enable StyleCop warning here?
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384224/using-this-keyword-in-c-sharp-visual-studio-vs-stylecop : "The official recommendation is to disable SA1101."

Comment: Edited example which was incorrect and a bit misleading. Hopefully it makes sense. I'm still interested in finding out if there's a way to re-enable a suppressed warning.